# Qual motivo do CURL do PHP ser tão lento? comparando ao wget/browse?

Tags: php, http, libcurl, wget

Tenho trabalhado com o `CURL` do `PHP 5.6`, ele é extremamente lento com relação a outros recursos como `wget/browse/file_get_contents`.
Em um `REQUEST POST` simples, ele tem atraso de 4-10 segundos comparando com outros recursos, já pesquisei em diversos lugares, muitos falam que é `DNS`, mas, eu já tentei colocar `IP`, `connection timeout` etc.
Tentei de tudo e nada de ficar rápido, e não é o lado do `request`, pois eu testo com diversos servidores famosos como Facebook ou Instagram, portais com servidor de latência extremamente poderosa, e nada, sempre tem um atraso.

Alguém tem alguma solução testada que melhore a performance do `CURL` do `PHP 5.6` ou outro recurso mais inteligente para se comunicar com protocolo `HTTP`?

Comment: Isso é estranho, geralmente o cURL é mais rápido (ou igual) do que os outro métodos, ao menos em todos os testes que fiz. Uma coisa que pode ajudar é usa o CACHE do DNS e também apenas utilizar o IPv4 ou invés de procurar por IPv6.

Comment: Poste o código completo utilizado para montar a requisição CURL, as vezes é alguma option mal definida.